# ReactJS: Cannot read property <issue>

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

> Problem: When setting my "completed" property to a boolean the values
>   in my to-do list wont get checked when using toDoData.map (item =>)

In my ToDoData.js i have set a property "completed" to true or false. Whenever i try it says **"Cannot read property 'completed' of undefined.**.
Also when i try to display the "text" property it wont accept the **.item,** but only with **props.item**. I have tried to read the code over and over but i cannot seem to find a solution for my problem.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react"


function Props(props) {
    return (
        <div>
      <h3><input type="checkbox" checked={props.item.completed}/></h3>      
    <p>{props.item.text}</p>
</div>

    )
}

export default Props
```

```
import React from "react";
import Props from "./props";
import ToDoData from "../ToDoData.js"

class ToDoapp extends React.Component{
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
theanswer:ToDoData
     }

     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)   
}

handleChange() {

}


render() {const ReturnToDo = ToDoData.map(item => <Props key={item.id} text={item.text} />)
  return ( <div> {ReturnToDo} 
  </div> 
    )
}
}

export default ToDoapp
```

```
const ToDoData = [

    { id: "1", 
    text: "Go and wash your clothes and grab some good food",
    completed: true

    },

    { id: "2", 
    text: "Go and wash your clothes and grab some good food",
     completed: true

    },

    { id: "3", 
    text: "Go and wash your clothes and grab some good food",
     completed: false

    },

    { id: "4", 
    text: "Go and wash your clothes and grab some good food",
    completed: false

    }   
]

export default ToDoData
```

Comment: you never pass an `item` prop to your `Props` component. So `props.item` will be undefined

Comment: Can you show me an code snippet? I dont quiet get it

Comment: RULE: whenever you get 'cannot read <foo> of undefined - something has gone wrong left of <foo>

Comment: Thank you, will keep in mind!

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem. Here:

```
function Props(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3><input type="checkbox" checked={props.item.completed}/></h3>      
      <p>{props.item.text}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You are trying to access **props.item.completed** but actually you are passing as props the actual **text** so it would be **props.text**.
if you take a look at the render function inside Todoapp component you have

```
render() {
  const ReturnToDo = ToDoData.map(item => <Props key={item.id} text={item.text}/>)

  return (<div>{ReturnToDo}</div> 
 )
}
```

You are passing
`<Props key={item.id} text={item.text}/>` what you should do is pass the whole item as props like `<Props key={item.id} item={item}/>` so you can use it inside Props component like you are trying to do.

Check out the example I made in codesanbox https://codesandbox.io/s/small-rain-4rhpv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Hope this helps

Comment: It works! I didnt read the tutorial correct. Thank you very much.
Can  you explain this for me ? item={item}?

Comment: So the item={item} is just used to print the data right?

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked out. Basically, you are passing a prop name item but you can name it whatever you want like for example todoItem or someItem or whatever name you want, the important part is that you pass in the actual item. For example: `<Props key={item.id} todoItem={item} />`. Is that clear?

Comment: it is very clear and thank you again very much, BUT if i change it to anything, like you wrote todoItem={item} i get the same error as before. I tried to change it in your code and it works i might be doing something wrong. One is JSX attribute the other is parameter of the data file

Comment: Yeah, now you have to change it inside the Props component like `props.todoItem` because you changed the name of the prop.

Comment: I tired to change the item to something else in your code and in my own and it doesent seem to work even though i change it inside the prop component. can you try it?

Comment: changed: https://codesandbox.io/s/small-rain-4rhpv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I must be blind. There is someplace i did something wrong and i still cannot find it but nevermind it works.